# Is it possible to instantiate a Storyboard builded ViewController in a swift project as an imported objective C class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have created a swift project with `storyBoard` and I have imported some `objective-C` class files(.h/.m) like presented in `Apple's Documentation`. My question is if it's possible to tell a `storyBoard` builded VC to be of custom class like the `objective-C` class that I have imported. When I import the `objective-C` class name in the identity inspector and I run the project I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: -[UITableViewController
>   loadView] loaded the "XXX" nib but didn't get a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

My problem had a very simple solution. I had taken a UIViewController from the object library instead of UITableViewController so it can understand the import of the Objective-C class.